# Ubuntu Shell Script - Use jq with args

Tags: json, shell, jq, args

I'm trying to edit a json file in a shell script with the jq program. The json file has the following format:

```
{
    "bla": {
        "test1": "True",
        "test2": "False"
    }
}´
```

I want to set a parameter to define which value from "bla" should be changed. I want to start the script for example like this:

> $ ./myscript.sh test1

I tried it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

jq --arg v $1 '.pokemon.$v = "True"' filters.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json filters.json
```

But it is not working. I'm getting the following error:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting IDENT
.pokemon.$v = "True"
         ^
1 compile error
```

Someone know how to solve this?

Comment: Quotes. `--arg v "$1"`, or else you have no guarantee of how many separate arguments to `jq` `$1` is parsed into by the shell.

Comment: PIDs are quite predictable, making code using the pattern you follow here vulnerable to symlink attacks (as a concrete example: If you're running `jq` as root and creating `/tmp/$$.json`, then someone *else* can make a bunch of `/tmp/*.json` files that are symlinks to `/etc/passwd` and thus cause you to unknowingly overwrite `/etc/passwd`). Using `mktemp` te create your temporary files doesn't have this vulnerability, or [the `inplace` command](https://github.com/nicowilliams/inplace).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - `jq -i` has a tortured history. In brief, it was removed, but will probably be re-instated one day.   In the meantime, `sponge` works well for many.

Comment: @Nono - In case you're wondering, values passed in via `--arg` show up as JSON strings. That's why .[$v] works.

Comment: @peak, indeed; I edited out the `jq -i` note (apparently before your comment was posted? Refresh is odd sometimes). I'm hesitant to recommend `sponge` here since it can't detect when the item before it in a pipeline exited with an error (except, I suppose, in cases where this results in zero-byte input, but I don't know if it actually *does* have an option for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `[...]` subscripting syntax instead of the `.` syntax if you want to use a variable in the subscript:

```
.pokemon[$v] = "True"
```